# Hadoop is crashing on startup - docker-compose (MacOS)

Tags: macos, docker, hadoop, docker-compose

We are using docker-compose to start an instance of Hadoop on a local dev machine (Mac).

Recently we began seeing the following error in the hadoop container, in the /var/log/hadoop-yarn-resource-manager.log file:

```
1-08-31 03:07:02,108 INFO  [main] ipc.CallQueueManager (CallQueueManager.java:<init>(75)) - Using callQueue: class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue scheduler: class org.apache.hadoop.ipc.DefaultRpcScheduler
2021-08-31 03:07:02,198 INFO  [main] service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:noteFailure(272)) - Service org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceTrackerService failed in state STARTED; cause: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Call From hadoop-master to null:0 failed on socket exception: java.net.SocketException: Unresolved address; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SocketException
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Call From hadoop-master to null:0 failed on socket exception: java.net.SocketException: Unresolved address; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SocketException
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.getServer(RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.java:139)
```

And we are seeing the following in /var/log/hadoop-yarn-nodemanager.log

```
2021-08-31 03:41:44,718 FATAL [main] nodemanager.NodeManager (NodeManager.java:initAndStartNodeManager(549)) - Error starting NodeManager
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Invalid host name: local host is: (unknown); destination host is: "hadoop-master":8031; java.net.UnknownHostException; For more det
ails see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/UnknownHost
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:230)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:120)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStart(NodeManager.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:547)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:594)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Invalid host name: local host is: (unknown); destination host is: "hadoop-master":8031; java.net.UnknownHostException; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Unkn
ownHost
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor30.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

We are looking into destination host is: "hadoop-master":8031  - we are not expecting “hadoop-master” or port  8031 anywhere.

docker-compose:

```
  version: '2.1' # We're using mem_limit so it stays version 2

services:
  
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    mem_limit: 256m

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:29092,EXTERNAL://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    mem_limit: 768m

  kafka_admin:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop
    container_name: kafka-admin
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    ports:
      - 9093:9000
    environment: 
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: kafka:29092
    mem_limit: 256m

  minio:
    image: minio/minio:RELEASE.2021-08-31T05-46-54Z
    container_name: minio
    ports:
      - 9094:9000
      - 9001:9001
    environment:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minio
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: minio123
      MINIO_REGION: us-east-1
    command: server /data --console-address ":9001"
    mem_limit: 512m

  presto:
    image: ahanaio/prestodb-sandbox:0.250
    container_name: presto
    ports:
      - 9095:8080
    volumes: 
      - ./presto/minio.properties:/opt/presto-server/etc/catalog/minio.properties
      - ./presto/create-table.sql:/opt/create-table.sql
      - ./presto/sync-partitions.sql:/opt/sync-partitions.sql
    mem_limit: 1024m

  hadoop:
    image: prestodb/hdp2.6-hive
    container_name: hadoop
    volumes:
      - ./hadoop/core-site.xml:/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml
    mem_limit: 2048m
```

and our core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>

    <!-- OOZIE proxy user setting -->
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.hosts</name>
        <value>*</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups</name>
        <value>*</value>
    </property>

    <!-- HTTPFS proxy user setting -->
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.httpfs.hosts</name>
        <value>*</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.httpfs.groups</name>
        <value>*</value>
    </property>

    <!-- Llama proxy user setting -->
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.llama.hosts</name>
        <value>*</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.llama.groups</name>
        <value>*</value>
    </property>

    <!-- Hue proxy user setting -->
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.hosts</name>
        <value>*</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.groups</name>
        <value>*</value>
    </property>

    <!-- Mapred proxy user setting -->
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.mapred.hosts</name>
        <value>*</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.mapred.groups</name>
        <value>*</value>
    </property>

    <!-- Hive impersonation -->
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.hosts</name>
        <value>*</value>
    </property>
  
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.groups</name>
        <value>*</value>
    </property>

    <!-- Hdfs impersonation -->
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hdfs.groups</name>
        <value>*</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hdfs.hosts</name>
        <value>*</value>
    </property>

    <!-- Minio properties -->
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.endpoint</name>
        <value>http://minio:9000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
        <value>minio</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
        <value>minio123</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.path.style.access</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.impl</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

Has anyone run into this issue with newer versions of Docker?

Comment: I dont think Docker is your problem. Is YARN and HDFS running in that one container? If not can you share the full compose file? 1) you shouldn't use `fs.defaultFS` and `fs.default.name`. 2) you don't need HDFS if you are using MinIO... 3) what is `hadoop-master` host supposed to be since your container is only named `hadoop`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for your comment!
I have removed `fs.defaultFS` and `fs.default.name`
and I included the full `docker-compose`
I am really not sure what `hadoop-master` is supposed to be. I would expect `hadoop` - the same name as the container
I am still seeing the same startup crashes.

Comment: Well, don't remove both, but you should be using the "correct one" for the Hadoop version you're running (which I think is `fs.default.name`), and youd want to set the value to be `s3a://<some_path>` to use minio rather than HDFS... But what happens if you rename `container_name: hadoop` to `container_name: hadoop-master`? And are you sure you aren't supposed to be starting some other HDFS containers because it seems like that is hard-coded somewhere else

Comment: Renaming the container to `hadoop-master` solved the issue. Thank you! Please feel free leave this info as an answer and I will accept it.